# Create array of objects from ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I am using DataTables with ajax and I am trying to dynamically generate a columns list as in the example here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html (only in my case I have display and order for all items).
I tried with this approach, but this doesn't work and I am guessing push my sub values wrong.

**Input (ajax result):**

```
[{
    "itemId": {
      "order": "BG007002",
      "display": "BG007002"
    },
    "builtDate": {
      "order": "2000-03-01",
      "display": "01.03.2000"
    },
    "openedDate": {
      "order": "2005-07-09",
      "display": "09.07.2005"
    },
    "buildingSize": {
      "order": 15000,
      "display": "15.000"
    }
  }, // ...
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
    { data: {
        _:    "itemId.display",
        sort: "itemId.order"
        }
    },
    { data: {
        _:    "builtDate.display",
        sort: "builtDate.order"
        }
    },
    { data: {
        _:    "openedDate.display",
        sort: "openedDate.order"
        }
    },
    { data: {
        _:    "buildingSize.display",
        sort: "buildingSize.order"
        }
    }
]
```

**My approach:**

```
var reportColsShort = $('#reportColsShort').text().slice(0,-1);
var aoCols = [];            
var colss = reportColsShort.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < reportColsShort.split(',').length; i++) {
    var aoColss = {};
    aoColss['data']['_'] = colss[i].display;
    aoColss['data']['sort'] = colss[i].order;
    aoCols.push(aoColss); // expected output
}
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot set property '_' of undefined.
```

**Update:**

Here is one more reference to what I am trying to achieve:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Examples

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays"; just objects and arrays.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Thanks for pointing this out. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: Within the question itself, please be more specific about "what doesn't" work.

Comment: I am not able to create the expected output dynamically and therefore cannot use this to set up DataTables as intended. I get the error "Cannot set property '_' of undefined." If I hard-code the expected output then it works fine.

Comment: _"my data set is generated dynamically so the columns will not always be the same_". You can build a second data structure - let's call it `var dynamicColumns` - and populate that with the data needed for a DataTables [`columns` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns). You can see an example of this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64249949/12567365). It's for a different source data structure, of course - but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the *ajax result* and then use a map [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  to structure your data like this:

```
const data = [{
    "itemId": {
      "order": "BG007002",
      "display": "BG007002"
    },
    "builtDate": {
      "order": "2000-03-01",
      "display": "01.03.2000"
    },
    "openedDate": {
      "order": "2005-07-09",
      "display": "09.07.2005"
    },
    "buildingSize": {
      "order": 15000,
      "display": "15.000"
    }
  }];

const mapResult = data.map((elem) => {
  let array = [];
  Object.keys(elem).forEach((key) => {
    
    const temp = {
      data: {
        _: elem[key].display,
        sort: elem[key].order
      }
    }
    array.push(temp);
  });
  return array;
});

console.log(mapResult);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Will try it now.

Comment: I tried with this and it looks good but my problem is that my data set is generated dynamically so the columns will not always be the same. Is there a way to use this approach dynamically, i.e. without hard-coding the column names ?

Comment: I would say no there isn't. If you don't know the exact order of data coming in, then without the keys of the original object ("itemId", "builtDate"...) after running a map function all you would have is a lot of random numbers: if one of "openedDate" or "buildDate' was missing you wouldn't know which one.

Comment: I also think that map is the wrong approach here but it should work with array.push I think.

Comment: I have made an update, is this what you were after?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your efforts ! This is almost it. I need to implement it with Ajax as in the solution from Viandante in the example here, with the Ajax result: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23262/load-ajax-data-with-custom-parameters . Can you show me how to apply your approach to this ?

Comment: Here are more examples for what I need: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: I can't help much more, I would say you need to read the bit under "Add data to the request by manipulating the data object:" from your second link. The error "data is not defined" is because you are calling the map function too early, you need to make the ajax request, get the data back, map the data then continue