# How to bind jQuery DataTable dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, grid

Is there any way that we can bind jQuery DataTable dynamically like we are doing in asp.net grid or Telerik rad grid by setting the property autoGeneratedColumns to true.

I want to use the same HTML table definition for all the data set to bind having different number and type of columns.

Comment: From the DataTables point of view, variations of this question has been asked several times on Stack Overflow - you can [research relevant questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+datatables+dynamic+columns). If those do not help, you can clarify why they do not help, and you can update your question with a [mre], describing the specific problem you are still facing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery DataTable add dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242502/jquery-datatable-add-dynamic-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you omit to set the columns of the grid, the widget will generate them for you. However, you should send the data from the backend as JSON or use a valid JS array. Additionally, you can dynamically generate the model so that you have the correct types associated with each field. Find further information in the dedicated KB article:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-generate-model-from-data